# How to get permission to access resource in Docker?

Tags: php, docker

I have docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
  webserver:
    image: php:7.4.3-apache
    ports:
      - "8181:80"
    volumes:
    - ./myprojectfoldername:/var/www/html
```

And I run command `docker-compose up -d`
Opening localhost:8181 and receiving 403:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 8181
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the user running the apache docker container does not have writes to access the files. You need to make sure that the user running containers have access to the files (the owner of the files) or use `root` user to run the apache server

Comment: no, i did docker copy . containderID:/var/www/html/ 
and now i see web site, but(!) I have another problem - my php code doesnt send message on email... why it could be ?